# '\' in string path disappears when trying to use it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a code that gets a part of a path, then uses it to load an image.
When I use the path instead of behaving as standard like expected, for example: `Main Folder\SubFolder\SubSubFolder` it's being used like that:`Main FolderSubFolderSubSubFolder` the whole '\' are missing. I know that when we have a string we add a `@` before so it doesn't happen but in this case I don't have a string that I write but a string that I get back.

Code:

```
@{
    string path = _Data.path;
    string ImgPath = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("Files") - 1, (path.Length - (path.LastIndexOf("Files") - 1)));

    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path); // _Data.path
    foreach (var file in filePaths)
    {
        var temp = file;

        List<string> set1 = path.Split('\\').Distinct().ToList();
        List<string> set2 = temp.Split('\\').Distinct().ToList();

        var diff = set2.Count() > set1.Count() ? set2.Except(set1).ToList() : set1.Except(set2).ToList();
        
        <img src="~/@ImgPath/@string.Join("", diff)" />
    }
}
```

As you can see, `ImgPath` is a part of a string that I get from my database, so I can't really add a `@` to it.
In addition, because it is an ASP NET project and I am in an `.cshtml` file, the `@` is used to write c# code. How do I make the path stay with the `\` when I use it to load the Image?

### After an Edit:

```
    @{
    string path = _Data.path;
    string ImgPath = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("Files") - 1, (path.Length - (path.LastIndexOf("Files") - 1)));
    string[] ImgPathArray = ImgPath.Split('\\');

    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path); // _Data.path
    foreach (var file in filePaths)
    {
        var temp = file;

        List<string> set1 = path.Split('\\').Distinct().ToList();
        List<string> set2 = temp.Split('\\').Distinct().ToList();

        var diff = set2.Count() > set1.Count() ? set2.Except(set1).ToList() : set1.Except(set2).ToList();
        
        <img src="~@string.Join("/", ImgPathArray)/@string.Join("", diff)" />
    }
}
```

### Error:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`

Comment: Yeah so `string.Join("/", diff)`?

Comment: `string.Join("/", diff)` works fine it's the ImgPath that doing the problem.

Comment: For example, if I use it now the path that I'll get is: `~/FilesRoad_ProblemsAccidentgM80oFarPLSnSVbp906JVwHxDXi2czTsdidOvFxnGTymN96cE6iQTWTtFKwRgiPZ/Banner template.jpg` you can see that the middle string is just a long string instead of a multiple directories

Comment: I sure hope the image itself doesn't have the word "Files" in the file name, or this whole thing will break. It's not a good idea to split based on a word in the path, rather by its hierarchy.

Comment: @gunr2171 you make a fair point.

Comment: That @ only works on string literals, not contents of string variables. You lost backslashes because you Split on them (separator is not included in the resulting fragments) and failed to add them on that Join

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Are you talking about the diff? the diff doesn't need backslashes. it is the Imgpath that does.

Comment: By the way, `path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("Files") - 1)` selects the same substring

Comment: If `_Data.path` contains backslashes after (1 char before) the last "Files", then they will still be in `ImgPath` - inside a string value a backslash is just another character. Only in literals can they have a special meaning

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Yes, if I open the project, not in IIS mode I can see the console, and the backslashes are there. I did some fixing, I'll upload it right away, I have a new error.

Comment: A 404 (presumably from trying to get an image) means that the path you created does not lead to a result. What *is* the value of that `src` attribute (check the browser). Also, apparently you just want to Replace \ with / in your ImgSrc